# Perl URI::Escape Ruby equivalent URI.escape

Tags: ruby, perl

Any idea if there's a way to have an exact equivalent in Ruby for Perl:

```
my $verysafe = uri_escape("foo", "\0-\377");
```

output: `%66%6F%6F`

Ruby's:

```
verysafe = URI.escape('foo')
```

output `foo`

doesn't return the same output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby you can provide the unsafe characters as a regular expression. In your case:

```
URI.escape('foo', /[\0-\377]/) # => "%66%6F%6F"
```